# Get element by rel and and class at same time?

Tags: jquery

Consider the HTML below :

```
 <a class="box" rel="1">  link </a>
 <a class="box" rel="8">  link </a>
```

How to select the a element that has the class "box" and rel="1" ?

I know how to do it with only one attribute, for example the code below will work but it will show both links:

```
  $(function() {
  $('.box').show(); // How can I get the class 'box' and the rel = '1' at the same time ??
  });
```

Comment: What do you mean by _has the class "first"_?

Comment: Sorry for that. it was a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach:

```
$('.box[rel="' + numberToLookFor + '"]'); 
// or just $('.box[rel=1]'), if this number is static
```

... in other words, just create a combined selector by placing two simple selectors together.

Note that there should be no whitespace between `.box` and square bracket - otherwise the latter will check for `.box` descendants.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery's [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

Here is an example:

```
$("[attribute='value']").someEvent();
```